# Application Tab on Teams Mobile iPhone (iOS) App does not load

Tags: ios, safari, microsoft-teams

We are building a **configurableTab** application in Microsoft Teams, and we have a new issue which started around the 21st March after a Teams App update.

- The tab does not load, but does display our SPA loading spinner.
- This only occurs on the iOS version of the Microsoft Teams Application.
- This only recently started occurring.
- The application is not yet available in the App Store.
- There are no indications on the server side of communications with the client app
- As it's the iOS Teams Application, there are no client logs available.
- Safari Desktop [Teams Preview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/safari-browser-support-1aac0a7c-35a8-42c1-a7df-f674afe234df) displays a similar error, however, as it's beta/preview, it may be unrelated.

Comment: Could you please try to update to any latest version if available? please do share your iOS Teams verson as well

Comment: I'm in the same team as Martin (the reporter). Versions are as follows: iOS 15.4, Microsoft Teams iPhone app 4.5.1

Comment: This turned out to be a regex being used in our code, that wasn't supported in Safari browsers. This made our app have an endless loading spinner within the Microsoft Teams App on iOS. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding answer from comment section for more visibility:*

This turned out to be a regex being used in our code, that wasn't supported in Safari browsers. This made our app have an endless loading spinner within the Microsoft Teams App on iOS. Now the issue is solved.